# javascript - check a function execution count and make it execute not more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, logic

I have used a plugin "isInViewport js" which lets you know when an element is in viewport and lets you do something when that happens.

So I have written a *counting* function which is a number counter function. This executes when an element *earn* is in viewport.

But this *counting* function starts executing every time the element comes into viewport. I want this function to execute not more than once.

This is the code I had written which runs fine but not as I expect:

```
$('.earn').on('inview', function (event, visible) {
        console.log('inview');

          if (visible == true) {
        console.log('inview count');

            counting();

          } else {
            $('#counter').text(0);
            $('#counter2').text(0+"$");
          }
        });
```

The pusedocode for what I am looking for is:

```
if(count of function == 0){
  executeFunction();
}
else{

}
```

Could someone please provide a solution for this through javascript or jquery?

Comment: Create global variable as 0. Increment it on function call. At the start of the function check that this variable less than necessary limit.

Comment: jQuery has `one()`, but it only executes the handler once, otherwise, use a counter etc.

Comment: @SergeyKotyushkin Your solution worked. Thank you so much! Simple and easy. :)

Comment: @adeneo I had already tried that but it only works with event handler like 'click'. did not work for me. But thank you so much for your answer. :)

Comment: @JohnEnosh, but you should know that global vars are not good)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need `counting` to run once, you can do something like this in your `inview` handler.

```
if (visible == true) {
  console.log('inview count');
  if (!this.is_counted) { // 'this' should refer to your element.earn
    counting();
    this.is_counted = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. I had followed the solution provided Sergey Kotyushkin in the comments above. But thank you so much for your solution too.. :)

Comment: @JohnEnosh Cool, hope it helped.